# Change Navbar background-color on scroll in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following ReactJS code, which work in this way. In scrolling 30px it change header background color on blue and in returning on 0px it became transparent. I think it working good. But my problem is in another thing. I want only it work on my home page ("/"). How can I achieve it?

[My COde](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-active-class-le29u)

I try this

```
    backgroundColor: change && useLocation().pathname == "/" ? "blue" : "transparent"
```

But it's not help me.

In other cases("), as it was originally, let it remain. Please, I need help.

Comment: your example is working fine to me

Comment: in other pages (contact and about) on scrolling it change his bgColor on blue and in returning on 0px in transparent. this should not be․ Իt should only work on home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need

`backgroundColor: useLocation().pathname === "/" && change ? "transparent" : 'blue',`